# Update date for each record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I am trying something like this

```
 DECLARE @CreateDate DATETIME, @iCount BIGINT
 SET @iCount=0
 SET @CreateDate=DATEADD(s,.5,GETDATE()) 
 DECLARE iCreateDate CURSOR FOR
 SELECT ID
 FROM Table AS 
 WHERE CreateDate IS null ;
 OPEN iCreateDate ;
 FETCH FROM iCreateDate ;
 UPDATE Table
 SET CreateDate = @CreateDate
 WHERE CURRENT OF iCreateDate ;
 SET @iCount=@iCount+1
 WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.5';
 WHILE     (SELECT COUNT(ID)
 FROM Table AS 
 WHERE CreateDate IS NULL) > 0
 FETCH NEXT FROM iCreateDate INTO @CreateDate

 CLOSE iCreateDate ;
 DEALLOCATE iCreateDate ;
GO
```

Comment: You should explain what it is that you wan to do instead of just posting some code. Also, what's the question?

Comment: Sorry. I am trying to populate the createdate with getdate(), but each record is about .5 seconds different. Basically have a different date a half second later for each record. BTW, I dont have to do a cursor if someone can think of easier way

Comment: Are you using a date as the primary key on a table? If so, why is it not set as the primary key or at least a unique index to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.100).aspx) to generate a row number for each and use that as a multiplier for your time increment.

```
WITH cteNullDates AS (
    SELECT ID, 
           CreateDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
        FROM Table
        WHERE CreateDate IS NULL
)
UPDATE cteNullDates
    SET CreateDate = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, RowNum * 500, GETDATE());
```